Hiding input cells in presentation and ready to use output
I'm working on a notebook about Newton's method, but I'm struggling to get the layout as neat as I would like. I want to display only the output of my current code,
f[x_] := x^x - Cos[x];
fprime[x_] := f'[x];
n[x_] := x - f[x]/fprime[x];

x0 = 2;
racine = x /. FindRoot[f[x], {x, 2.5}];
xi = n[x0];
listePtsFct = {{x0, 0}, {x0, f[x0]}};

While[xi != racine,
  listePtsFct = Join[listePtsFct, {{xi, 0}, {xi, f[xi]}}];
  xi = n[xi]
  ];

Manipulate[Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2.5}, PlotStyle -> Darker@Blue],
  Graphics[{Darker@Red, PointSize[Medium], 
    Point[listePtsFct[[1 ;; a]]], Line[listePtsFct[[1 ;; a]]]}]
  ]
 , {a, 1, Length[listePtsFct], 1} 
 ]

similar to how it's done in this other notebook I came across.

Additionally, I'd like to open my Newton's method notebook and have the Manipulate function ready to use without having to wait for it to run. When I open my notebook, I only see a red graphic.


You could select the cells you want not to show, then do Cell->Cell properties-> and uncheck the Open option.   Not sure if this is what you meant.

Hide Input in a Notebook.

Thank you for the link.
I had tried it before posting my question, but unfortunately, it still doesn't resolve my issue. When I open my notebook, the Manipulate function is not ready to use. Instead, I only see a red graphic, and the output doesn’t appear correctly.
Is there a way to ensure that the Manipulate function is fully initialized and ready to interact with as soon as I open the notebook?

Try the Initialization option

@LilGreg, please read Saving Definitions of Functions Used inside Manipulate to see the purpose of SaveDefinitions -> True.
